# How to run form included in .exe from an external .scx form Visual foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

Using Visual Foxpro 9, I have an exe that runs an external form .scx present in the disk. Let's say pippo.exe calls external.scx form present on the disk.
Everything runs ok.

Now in the form external.scx I need a button that runs a form called form1 that is present into the main exe. Visual Foxpro says that the form1.scx is not found on the disk. The form external.scx cannot be included in the exe because it changes dynamically.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can have form1 as a class and your external.scx could instantiate it providing the location (exe) as well.

PS: I wouldn't do such a thing. Instead of whole form being external, things that it calls might be external.